# Cannot read property 'selectionEnd' of null in aoutoComplete material UI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a problem with autoComplete 
the react-text-mask is like this :

```
<MaskedInput
  {...other}
  ref={ref => {
    inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
    return ref;
  }}
  mask={[
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    ' ',
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    ' ',
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
  ]}
  placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
/>;
```

and the autoComplete component is like this:

```
<AmountAutoComplete
  options={this.state.autoCompleteOptions.map(option => option.title)}
  renderInput={params => {
    return (
      <TextField
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={e => {
          onValueChange(e.currentTarget.value, '');
        }}
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: this.TextMaskCustom,
        }}
      />
    );
  }}
/>;
```

and the error is

Cannot read property 'selectionEnd' of null
    at handleClick (useAutocomplete.js:763)

and in useAutocomplete.js:763 have the error about inputRef:

var handleClick = function handleClick() {
    if (firstFocus.current && inputRef.current.selectionEnd - inputRef.current.selectionStart === 0) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
      inputRef.current.select();
    }

Comment: have you created the ref before you used it? Can you show us the code?

Comment: I use the exact pattern of material UI documentation
https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/

Comment: ref from the URL that you've provided comes from props, again have you created your ref before and can you show us the chunk of code where you're creating it?

Comment: and I just use ref in MaskInput like documentation and I don't use it anywhere else in class

Comment: ```javascript
TextMaskCustom = (props) => {
        const { inputRef, ...other } = props;

        return (
            <MaskedInput
                {...other}
                ref={ref => {
                    inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
                }}
                mask={[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
                placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
            />
        );
    };
```

Comment: ok, can you `console.log(inputRef)` inside your class under `{ const { inputRef, ...other } = props;` that statement

Comment: this is the log of inputRef:   ƒ (refValue) {
      Object(_setRef__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])(refA, refValue);
      Object(_setRef__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])(refB, refValue);
    }

Comment: wait, why are you returning ref here: `ref={ref => {
    inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
    return ref;
  }}`

Comment: yes I found the problem

Answer (score 2):

I should send params into textField like this:

```
<TextField
    {...params}
     InputProps={{
     ...params.InputProps,
    }} 
 />
```